# Adding future date/time to TrustPilot script in Magento Packing Slip

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, date

I am about to add a "Structured Data Snippet" to my Magento packing slip emails, which should include a future date.

The snippet looks like this (example data):

```
<script type="application/json+trustpilot">
{
  "recipientName": "Name MacNameson",
  "recipientEmail": "customer@email.com",
  "referenceId": "1234abcd",
  "preferredSendTime": "2016-02-29T13:37:00"
}
</script>
```

...and the preferredSendTime should be set to 7 days from now. Time could be 18:00 on them all..

So for instance; if the packing slip is created 2018-03-14 in the morning some time, the value should show "2018-03-21T18:00:00" (which is 18:00 the evening 7 days later)

How can I achieve this? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your email template (via editor at Magento admin -> System -> Transactional emails), do;

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/custom/trustpilot.phtml' order=$order}}
```

Make new file in your template folder, `app/design/frontend/[your theme]/default/email/custom/trustpilot.phtml`

Here's how I do it, I define different for UK and Worldwide, but you can change as you wish (trustpilot.phtml);

```
<?php $order = $this->getOrder(); ?>
<?php if ($order) { ?>
<?php $country = $order->getShippingAddress()->getCountryModel()->getName(); ?>
<?php $date = $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT); ?>
<?php
  if ($country == "United Kingdom") {
    $nextDate =  Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date." +10 days"));
  } else {
    $nextDate =  Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date." +21 days"));
  }

  $nextDate = str_replace(' ', 'T', $nextDate); ?>

<script type="application/json+trustpilot">
{
  "recipientName": "<?php echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname(); ?>",
  "referenceId": "<?php echo $order->getIncrementId(); ?>",
  "preferredSendTime": "<?php echo $nextDate; ?>",
}
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that. But don't you add customer email address, if not.. how will Trustpilot be able to send to them? Or will they perhaps fetch the email address from the email itself?

Comment: Sorry, you just BCC the trustpilot AFS service in on emails, it gets the email from the recipient @espen

Comment: Sure, that´s what I was thinking about. Can I ask where in the email template to put the {{block type... code? In between the html-tags, or somewhere else?  Thanks.   Btw.. I think there is a misspell in the template-folder above, should be a folder "template" after /default/ (just to make the answer 100% correct).

Comment: Magento admin -> System -> Transactional emails

Comment: Hi. Sorry for my late reply, have been away for some time. I have tried the above solution, without luck. The BCC is reaching Trustpilot, but none of the information (except the email address) is fetched by TP. I guess they get the email address from the email itself, but the recipientName, referenceId and preferredSendTime is not there. I know the template is using the trustpilot.phtml file (I added some text outside the code which I could see when previewing the template). Any suggestions whan can be the problem? Thank you. -Espen

Comment: Nevermind, my fault.. seemed like the templates in Magento admin -> System -> Transactional emails didn´t work at all, and that the ones in app/locale/nb_NO/template/email/sales/ was used instead. Added my changes there instead, and all good. Thank you for your help! -Espen

Comment: @Espen no problem, i assumed the default en_US. Thanks!